# Java - objects access control for users

Tags: java, spring

I don't even know if this question title is correct - forgive if it doesn't. I have such problem:

My web application can be accessed only by logged users. Each user is represented as `User` entity which is saved in database.

There are some other entity classes: `A`, `B`, `C`... also kept in database. Each object of classes `A`, `B`... could be created by any user.
But `user1` shouldn't see objects created by `user2`.

**Question:**

How I can make such access control?

**My naive idea:**

I can add `User` property (column in case of DB table) for EVERY entity class. And during object creation, this property will take current user id. So far it is ok for me. But then I must add current user to every database select. And this is problematic in some way.

For example, using Spring JPA instead of:

```
public interface MessageRepository extends JpaRepository<Message, Long> {
    List<Message> findByReceiveDateBetween(Date from, Date to);
}
```

I must use:

```
public interface MessageRepository extends JpaRepository<Message, Long> {
    List<Message> findByReceiveDateBetweenAndUser(Date from, Date to, User user);
}
```

My application is written in Java with Spring.

How do such access control?

Comment: It sounds like you already know how to do it. Why is it a problem to add the current user to each database select? Sure, it is a little extra typing, but if you want to select based on user, you have to do it.

Comment: This operation is routine (repeatable) so I thought that there is some better way to not adding `user` to any select manually. Moreover I heard something about ACL so I thought that maybe someone could suggest better solution than my naive.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely need to tag each entity with the ID of their creator on the database level.